# Is it possible to use custom java class to throw an exception in Crashlytics with Nativescript Android?

Tags: android, nativescript, crashlytics

I'm trying to return my Javascript exceptions in Crashlytics. It works but it all appears under the problem :

```
Runtime.java com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative
```

in the Crashlytics dashboard. I'd rather see my problem list like this :

```
MyScreen1.ts org.mycompany.monapp.myScreen1
MyScreen2.ts org.mycompany.monapp.myScreen2
```

I know that Crashlytics is not made to handle JavaScript errors but I would like to simulate this behavior as closely as possible. I tried to log my exception form a custom java class like this :

```js
@JavaProxy("org.demonativescript.MyErrorHandler")
export class MyErrorHandler extends java.lang.Object {
    constructor() {
        super();
        return global.__native(this);
    }

    sendCrash() : void{
        crashlytics.sendCrashLog(new MyCustomException("My Custom Excep"));
    }
};
```

But since the exception is still logged from the JavaScript runtil, the problem appears under :

```
Runtime.java com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative
```

Comment: Checkout the [error handling section of docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/error-handling), you may write your own error handler and send the logs to crashlytics in `handlerError` method of your error handler.

Comment: Have you found a way to properly group them?

Comment: No, unfortunately. We decided to use Sentry to track JS crashes and keep Crashlytics only for native stack crashes